# wpf, c#, get real height of uielement while adding childs in a loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to add blocks (paragraphs) to a FlowDocument and to stop when reaching a specific height:

```
        FlowDocumentScrollViewer fld = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer();
        fld.Document = new FlowDocument();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(new Run("Calling this method has no effect if layout is unchanged, or if neither arrangement nor measurement state of a layout is invalid."));
            fld.Document.Blocks.Add(p1);
            fld.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0));
            fld.UpdateLayout();
            fld.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0));
            System.Windows.Size msize = fld.RenderSize;
            if (msize.Height > 400)
                break;
        }
```

Now my questions is: How can I get the real size or rendered size of the FlowDocumentScrollViewer in the loop? The render-process is not started until the loop has ended. But I need the height to end the loop. UpdateLayout() doesn't seem to do the job. Does anyone know how to get the rendered height?

Comment: Not sure if this can work at all. The actual height of the document depends on several factors that are unknown until it is actually rendered, e.g. the width of the FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

Comment: I can define the Width of the FlowDocumentScrollViewer before starting the loop. That would be possible ... Would it then be possible to get the real height?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000177/1136211

Comment: The question in your linked post is if it is possible to get the real height of the FlowDocument without an UIElement. But I have an UIElement - the FlowDocumentScrollViewer. And the linked post doesn't show any solution for the problem ...

Comment: Read it again. The proposed solution is to call Arrange to get the actual height.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I thought that would help and I changed the code (plaese see above). Unfortunately that didn't help ....

Comment: You can execute the code yourself, it can be executed without further additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
fld.Document.Blocks.Add(p1);
fld.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
fld.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), fld.DesiredSize));
fld.UpdateLayout();
```

One has to call exactly these methods.
Measure with Double.PositiveInfinity is important and aferwards Arrange with DesiredSize.
Then ActualHeight is updated and has the correct value.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
fld.ActualHeight
```

"Get the rendered height of this element."

[Microsoft about ActualHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight?view=netframework-4.7.2)

But as autor and MS says the ActualHeight is 'filled' after being rendered. With don't happen within the loop.

Comment: msize.ActualHeight doesn't exist. You mean fld.ActualHeight I suppose? But this doesn't work fld.ActualHeight is not updated by UpdateLayout() unfortunately.Not within the loop.